# How does the whole word setting affect searching

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

If I search `[>]` in Sublime editor with regex on. Then it matches all `>` following alphanumeric characters. E.g. `>` in `<li`**`>`**`as</li>`  is selected but no `>` is selected from `<li></li>`. Similarly `[<]` matches `<` from `s`**`<`**`li></li>` but not from `<li></li>`.

[image]

So, how do I make sublime search all `<`?

P.S: Strangely the following text contains **`n`**`o`**`w`**`h`**`i`**`t`**`e`**`s`**`p`**`a`**`c`**`e.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshot, it looks like you are using the "Whole Word" option. So I think it should work if you press the little double quote symbol in the bottom left (or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> when your cursor is in the search box).

Comment: What does the `Whole Word` option do by the way?

Comment: In sublime, I think it sticks a `\b` at the beginning and end of your search text to match at [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work fine. Is this what you are searching?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work the same for me. I am using Sublime Build 3114. I've added the snapshot too.

Comment: @user31782 Look at my options on the bottom left and look at yours; you are trying to match the whole word.